# jquery closest() or children not working

Tags: jquery

jquery code :-

```
$('.cycle-status-update')
  .on('mouseenter', (function(){
    $(this).closest('.delete-status-update-link').show();
  }))
  .on('mouseleave', (function(){
    $(this).closest('.delete-status-update-link').hide();
  }))
```

html code :-

```
.status-partial
    -@user.status_updates.latest.limit(5).each do |status_update|
        .row-fluid.cycle-status-update{:class => cycle("dark", "light")}
            .row-fluid
                .span11
                    = status_update.status
                .span1
                    .delete-status-update-link
                        %strong= link_to "X", [@user,status_update], :remote => true, :method => :delete, :class => "delete-status-update"
            .row-fluid
                .time-ago-in-words
                    ="#{time_ago_in_words(status_update.created_at)} ago"
```

what could be the issue here ?

Comment: -1 (Can be undone) That's not HTML code.

Comment: Please add your HTML code. With out that we could not find what closest element you are looking for :)

Comment: its haml code which compiles into html

Comment: @DevR That's nice. However, it is **not** HTML code and it is **not** relevant to jQuery. It's the equivalent of showing PHP or normal Ruby and claiming it is HTML: it isn't.

Comment: he is using HAML code....

Comment: @bipen And, again, **not** relevant. The HTML, which is *not provided*, would be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find('.delete-status-update-link').show();
```

Comment: It should work, but explain *why*. Alternatively, explain why `closest()` doesn't work.

Comment: @bipen thanks, it works, not sure why closest was not working

Comment: @DevR Read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) .. it's a slightly confusing name, perhaps, but it is *well documented*.

Comment: @pst thanks I didn't knew it will be available in the documentation

Comment: @pst  thanks... i was about to post a link to the document... :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with your code, `(function` extra `(` before function and after `)`:

```
$('.cycle-status-update')
     .on('mouseenter', (function(){
     $(this).closest('.delete-status-update-link').show();
}))//<----here
.on('mouseleave', (function(){ //<--before function
    $(this).closest('.delete-status-update-link').hide();
}))
//^----here
```

try this:

```
$('.cycle-status-update').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $('.delete-status-update-link').show();
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('.delete-status-update-link').hide();
});
```